# How to connect web3 to main ethereum network using python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, blockchain, ethereum, web3py

I am using `web3.py` on my private/test network though:

```
from web3 import Web3, HTTPProvider
w3 = Web3(HTTPProvider("https://private-ip:8545"))
```

For making connection to my private network i use this method and
after performing all the oprations and testing i want to connect my API to main ethereum network.

So, my question is that how can i connect to main ethereum network ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use the URL of a node in the main Ethereum network. That could be one you run or one someone else makes available publicly.

[Infura](https://infura.io) runs one such public node.

Comment: So, according to you if i use `https://infura.io/` in `HTTPProvider` in will connect to main ethereum network ?

Comment: No, but if you use `https://mainnet.infura.io/<your key here>`, then you will be connected to a node in the main Ethereum network.

Comment: Oohh.. Fine! It seems like i need to sign up for infura first. Is there some other way like connecting via IPCProvider or RPC calls to main network ?

Comment: You can connect to any node, including one you run yourself.

Comment: Can you provide me a link or some info how to do that ?

Comment: How to do what? You just enter the URL of the node.

Comment: Oohh.. Ok! Thanks for help! :)